# Add a total count at end of proc tabulate

Tags: sas, frequency, proc

I have a `Proc Tabulate` output with row percentages, and I want a total count of all respondents for each summary variable. The closest I get is that it adds a row below each variable for the `count`, but I really only need an additional column at the end that represents the `total count`.

```
PROC TABULATE DATA = CHSS2017 f=10.2 S=[foreground=black just=c cellwidth=75]; 
CLASS EDUC
      AREA
      AGE 
      SEX 
      CENRACE 
      POVERTY 
      EDUC 
      INSURE 
      HEALTH
      Q21;

CLASSLEV EDUC     / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.];
CLASSLEV AREA     / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.];
CLASSLEV AGE      / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.];
CLASSLEV SEX      / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.];
CLASSLEV CENRACE  / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.];
CLASSLEV POVERTY  / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.];
CLASSLEV INSURE   / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.];
CLASSLEV HEALTH   / style=[font_weight=medium background=colfmt.]; 
CLASSLEV Q21;

TABLE AREA    = 'Area in Region' * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      AGE     = 'Age'            * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      SEX                        * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      CENRACE = 'Race'           * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      POVERTY = 'Poverty Status' * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      EDUC                       * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      INSURE                     * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.) 
      HEALTH                     * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.), Q21 = ' ' ALL*f=8;
RUN;
```

I keep trying to play around with adding "*n" or "*all" to the summary variables (Area, Sex, Age), but only get errors. My desired output should look like image, except that the "Count" column is the total sum not 100 or 100%

[Full table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g0mZ.png)

```
data WORK.CLASS(label='Survey Data');
   infile datalines dsd truncover;
   input age:3. sex:3. cenrace:3. q21:3. regionwt:16.;
 datalines;
5 4 2 2 0.1214634338
5 3 2 2 1.1946976229
7 4 2 2 0.6734857715
7 4 2 2 2.5191297921
5 3 2 1 0.2390983852
 ;;;;
```

Comment: Without data it's kind of hard to say, but I would expect an ALL to work, depending on where you want all, that's not clear from your picture.

Comment: how do i add sample data?

Comment: Edit your question and post as code snipped, to get the data step code follow the instructions here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-a-data-step-version-of-your-data-AKA-generate/ta-p/258712

Answer (score 0):

Without data it's hard to answer, but try this:

```
TABLE AREA    = 'Area in Region' * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      AGE     = 'Age'            * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      SEX                        * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      CENRACE = 'Race'           * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      POVERTY = 'Poverty Status' * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      EDUC                       * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      INSURE                     * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.) 
      HEALTH                     * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF.)
      ALL                                                , Q21 = ' ';
```

EDIT: Re-reading your question, I think this is what you want. Add the N with the ROWPCTN but after with nothing in between. You can add a format if needed. You likely need to do this for each one as well.

```
AREA    = 'Area in Region' * (ROWPCTN='   '*f=PCTF. N*f=8.)
```

Comment: Adding an ALL to the table group just adds a new row at the bottom with counts, I need basically the same thing but as a column.

Comment: Try moving ALL to after Q21 then.

Comment: If that doesn't work and you need further help, please post sample data and a better image of what you need because it's not clear from the current image.

Comment: Adding ALL to after Q21 gets me an extra column at the end, but it's populated with a total percentage. I need the total count for that row.